# How does the criteria $\nabla F(x_0) = \lambda \nabla G(x_0)$ guarantee that $x_0$ is a maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I'm attempting to figure out why Lagrange Multipliers work, and I have the following setup. Suppose we wish to maximize $F : \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with respect to the constraint $G = c$ where $G:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $L$ be the level surface $G = c$. Suppose $x_0\in L$, and $u$ is tangent to $L$ at $x_0$. I want to show that if $\nabla F\cdot u > 0$ then we can move along $L$ and find a point $x_0'\in L$ with $F(x_0')>F(x_0)$, hence requiring that $\nabla F\cdot u = 0$ for $x_0$ to be a maximum.

My problem is that the condition $f'(x_0)>0$ isn't enough to guarantee that there is an interval $[x_0,\ x_0+\delta]$ on which $f$ is increasing (for example, take $f(x) = x^2\sin^2\left(\frac1x\right) + \frac12 x$ for nonzero $x$, and $f(0)=0$). So essentially, if we look at $f(t) = F(x_0+tu)$, the statement $f'(0) > 0$ is not enough to assume that $f$ is strictly increasing on any neighbourhood of zero, and so $F$ isn't increasing in any neighbourhood of $x_0$ meaning we can't necessarily guarantee that it's increasing along $L$ in the direction of $u$. Hence, $\nabla F\cdot u>0$ isn't enough to guarantee that we can find another point $x_0'\in L$ near $x_0$ so that $F(x_0')>F(x_0)$.

If my logic isn't flawed, then how come Lagrange multipliers work? How do we know that $\nabla F\cdot u = 0$ for all tangent vectors $u$ to $L$ at $x_0$ is enough to guarantee that $x_0$ maximizes $F$ on $L$? Is it like, $\nabla F\cdot u>0$ isn't enough to guarantee that $x_0$ *isn't* a maximum, but $\nabla F\cdot u = 0$ *is*?

Comment: Based on the example you gave I suspect you might need more than $F\in C^0$ for this to work. Perhaps $F\in C^1$ or $C^2$ is enough.

Comment: Sometimes the application hands us a bit of good fortune in which the only critical point (vanishing first derivatives) happens to be the global maximum.  But as you can see, this need not be true in general.

Comment: Check out this formulation here, where one considers the constraint $G$ has a manifold and it explores the function $F$ as a function on the manifold http://planetmath.org/lagrangemultipliersonmanifolds

Comment: @hardmath so essentially, the condition that a maximum satisfies $\nabla F\cdot u = 0$ is necessary, but not sufficient? And it just so happens that for most "nice" functions it works out?

Comment: Right.  Things don't magically get better because we use Lagrange multipliers to impose a constraint, but in many "physical" situations the interpretation is felicitous.

Comment: You wrote that $f'(x_0) \gt 0 $  "isn't enough to guarantee that there is an interval $[x_0,x_0+\delta]$ on which $f$ is increasing", but it is enough to guarantee an interval on which every value of $f(x)$ exceeds $f(x_0)$.

Comment: @hardmath You are correct, that was my mistake. When looking at the $\epsilon-\delta$ form of $f'(x_0)>0$ I made the mistake of assuming that you would not be able to determine the parity of $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$, but you can indeed assume it is at least *positive*.